# Add missing rows for groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data with a `country`, `year` and `value` column. the max(year) is 1985 and min(year) is 2016 but not all country have data of all year(1985-2016). So to plot comparable bar plot between countries, I want to add `value` 0 for missing year for each country.

for example:

```
df -->
    country year    value
0   India   2040    354
1   India   2041    357
2   India   2042    454
3   USA     2040    454
4   USA     2041    436
```

As USA don't have 2042 data so adding it result into:

```
    country year    value
0   India   2040    354
1   India   2041    357
2   India   2042    454
3   USA     2040    454
4   USA     2041    436
5   USA     2042    0
```

How to do it for each country in my data?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The `max(year)` as far as I can see is 2042. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

We can convert "year" to a Categorical column and then allow pandas GroupBy to do the heavy lifting:

```
df['year'] = pd.Categorical(df['year'], categories=df['year'].unique())
df.groupby(['country','year'], as_index=False).first()

  country  year  value
0   India  2040  354.0
1   India  2041  357.0
2   India  2042  454.0
3     USA  2040  454.0
4     USA  2041  436.0
5     USA  2042    NaN
```

---

Another idea is reindexing:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['country'].unique(), df['year'].unique()])

(df.set_index(['country', 'year'])
   .reindex(mux)
   .reset_index()
   .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1))

  country  year  value
0   India  2040  354.0
1   India  2041  357.0
2   India  2042  454.0
3     USA  2040  454.0
4     USA  2041  436.0
5     USA  2042    NaN
```

Important caveat: Neither of these solutions will handle duplicate rows well. You will need to dedupe the rows by adding a uniquely identifying column, possibly using `GroupBy.cumcount`.

Answer (score 6):

Let us try `pivot` then `stack`

```
out = df.pivot(*df).stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='value')
  country  year  value
0   India  2040  354.0
1   India  2041  357.0
2   India  2042  454.0
3     USA  2040  454.0
4     USA  2041  436.0
5     USA  2042    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) can help with missing rows; it can handle duplicates as well :

```py
#pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.complete('country', 'year').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 
  country  year  value
0   India  2040    354
1   India  2041    357
2   India  2042    454
3     USA  2040    454
4     USA  2041    436
5     USA  2042      0
```