# Pandas interpolation adding rows by group with different ranges for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, interpolation

I am trying to add rows to a DataFrame interpolating values in a column by group, and fill with missing all other columns.  My data looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import random

random.seed(42)
data = {'group':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c' ],
        'value' : [1, 2, 5,  3, 4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 9],
        'other': random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
print(df)
  group  value  other
0     a      1     82
1     a      2     15
2     a      5      4
3     b      3     95
4     b      4     36
5     b      5     32
6     b      7     29
7     c      4     18
8     c      7     14
9     c      9     87
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
   group  value  other
      a      1     82
      a      2     15
      a      3     NaN
      a      4     NaN
      a      5     NaN
      b      3     95
      b      4     36
      b      5     32
      b      6     NaN
      b      7     29
      c      4     18
      c      5     NaN
      c      6     NaN
      c      7     14
      c      8     NaN
      c      9     87
```

For example, group `a` has a range from 1 to 5, `b` from 3 to 7, and `c` from 4 to 9.

The issue I'm having is that each group has a different range. I found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451188/8692138) that works assuming a single range for all groups. This could work using the global min and max and dropping extra rows in each group, but since my data is fairly large adding many rows per group quickly becomes unfeasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
>>> df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('value').reindex(np.arange(x['value'].min(), x['value'].max() + 1))).drop(columns='group').reset_index()
   group  value  other
0      a      1   82.0
1      a      2   15.0
2      a      3    NaN
3      a      4    NaN
4      a      5    4.0
5      b      3   95.0
6      b      4   36.0
7      b      5   32.0
8      b      6    NaN
9      b      7   29.0
10     c      4   18.0
11     c      5    NaN
12     c      6    NaN
13     c      7   14.0
14     c      8    NaN
15     c      9   87.0
```

We group on the `group` column and then re-index each group with the range from  the min to the max of the `value` column

Answer (score 1):

One option is with the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which can be helpful in exposing explicitly missing rows (and can be helpful as well in abstracting the reshaping process):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

new_value = {'value' : lambda df: range(df.min(), df.max()+1)}

# expose the missing values per group via the `by` parameter
df.complete(new_value, by='group', sort = True)

   group  value  other
0      a      1   82.0
1      a      2   15.0
2      a      3    NaN
3      a      4    NaN
4      a      5    4.0
5      b      3   95.0
6      b      4   36.0
7      b      5   32.0
8      b      6    NaN
9      b      7   29.0
10     c      4   18.0
11     c      5    NaN
12     c      6    NaN
13     c      7   14.0
14     c      8    NaN
15     c      9   87.0
```